# Is there a way to gain new rivals?

Tags: europa-universalis-iv

I'm actually too big and no one can be my rival. There is no more power projection points I can get.

**Is there a trick to obtain a new rival in this situation ?..**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you may only select rivals from nations of comparable power. If you've become much stronger than everybody else, there simply is no one left to rival you. This is a good point to end your game, unless you want to go for an achievement.